# Views expose filter of start and end dates

Tags: 7, datetime, views

I want an expose filter of start date and end date. I want to show the events that have start or end date between these two dates. If end date is not given in filter then display all the events having start date greater than filter's start date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the filter like that :

```
Start Date >= Filter's Stat Date

End Date <= Filter's End Date
```